# Why inflating layout at constructor of CustomView

Tags: android, android-layout

Every example of custom group view that I see inflates the layout at the constructor.

But for me, everything that inherits from view should inflate the layout at the onCreateView.

Why that "rule" isn't followed in the custom group view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because [there is no `onCreateView()` on `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), and hence a custom `View` cannot inflate anything there.

You are certainly welcome to write your own method that happens to be named `onCreateView()` and use it for something, but that is largely independent of Android's `View` framework.